# Driver info: driver.version: unknown error running Selenium and Codeception in DDEV (Apple Silicon)

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ddev

I was using VirtualBox for development when i had a windows pc. Later i bought a Macbook M1 and installed the DDEV instead of VirtualBox.
In my old development virtualbox, i installed selenium and chromedriver in Virtualbox. With this setup i could run Codeception Tests.

Since i'm using DDEV for development, i tired to install Selenium-chromedriver with following tutorials:

https://dev.to/tomasnorre/codeception-ddev-selenium-docker-36kk

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/Testing/ProjectTesting.html

My docker-compose.selenium.yaml File

```
version: '3.6'
services:
 selenium:
   container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-chrome
   image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
   environment:
     - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
     - HTTP_EXPOSE=4444
   external_links:
     - ddev-router:$DDEV_HOSTNAME
```

codeception.yaml File

```
# suite config
suites:
   acceptance:
       actor: AcceptanceTester
       path: .
       modules:
           enabled:
               - WebDriver:
                   url: http://test.ddev.site
                   host: ddev-test-chrome
                   browser: chrome
               - \Helper\Acceptance
```

I get following Error when i try to execute a Test in `ddev ssh` with `php vendor/bin/codecept run tests/FirstCest.php`

```
  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException] Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: '4916a3762177', ip: '172.18.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.76-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: '4916a3762177', ip: '172.18.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.76-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Is it possible, that the errors are related to M1-Chip or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated 2023-11-18**: There are better images to use these days, and there's a nice DDEV add-on that handles both AMD64 and ARM64. Try the [ddev-selenium-standalone-chrome](https://github.com/ddev/ddev-selenium-standalone-chrome) add-on, or use the image it's based on.

Original Answer:
The [selenium/standalone-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/tags) image is not built for arm64 (Mac M1). In fact, the chrome package it probably derives from is not available at all for arm64.

However, the chromium package *is* available for arm64. You may be able to use justinribeiro/chrome-headless:chromium, which is built for arm64.

Also, take a look at https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/docker-compose-services/headless-chrome, which has been updated to use the arm64 chromium image.

Comment: Thank you for response. I copied the following docker-compose in my ddev: https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/docker-compose-services/headless-chrome

I get following error:
`[ConnectionException] Can't connect to WebDriver at http://ddev-test-chrome:4444/wd/hub. Make sure that ChromeDriver, GeckoDriver or Selenium Server is running`

My codeception.yml
`
                - WebDriver:
                    url: http://test.ddev.site
                    host: ddev-test-chrome
                    browser: chrome
`
Adding "port: 9222" in codeception yml doesnt work either.

Comment: Yeah, I imagine you have to take a look at what the selenium/standalone-chrome container was doing that the regular chromium setup doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: '4916a3762177', ip: '172.18.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.76-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.13'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) **version** wasn't detected.

Presumably the main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=96.0.4664.45* (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).